# What does the response Merchant variation count exceeds limit mean?

Tags: square-connect

I'm trying to download my store's inventory
using the endpoint https://connect.squareup.com/v1/me/inventory.

It was working until this week.  I am now getting the following response:

> ```
> {"type":"forbidden","message":"Merchant variation count exceeds limit"}
> ```

Unfortunately, the Square documentation doesn't specify what this means?

Comment: It looks like we were having an issue with the inventory endpoint that should be resolved. Are you still getting this error?